# Add rows next to diagonal text in a table

Tags: tables

Im trying to add columns for "Datum", "Fahrt Nr" and "Linie" on the left side next to the diagonal text but i cant make it work, since it always appears above my table. Any idea how i could make it work?

Thanks!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%% Rotation
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \rot } { m }
  { 
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1 em }
      { 
        \hbox_overlap_right:n 
          { 
            \skip_horizontal:n { \fp_to_dim:n { 7 * cosd (\Angle) } } 
            \rotatebox{\Angle}{#1}
          } 
      } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\Angle{45}

\begin{threeparttable}

%% Part 1 of 3: the caption

\caption*{Fahrtenprotokoll:}
\label{tab:protokoll}

%% Part 2 of 3: the table
\begin{tabular}{l}
Fahrt Nr: \\
Linie: \\
Datum: \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{2.25cm}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{KP} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Bezeichnung} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen KP [s]}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit LSA [s]}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit HS [s]}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrgastwechselzeit [s]}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen HS [s]}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Sonstiges} \\ \hline
HS 1       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 1.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 1.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 2       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 2.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 2.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 3       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 3.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 3.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 4       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 4.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 4.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
\multicolumn{3}{r|}{Gesamt:}  &  &  &  &     \\ \cline{4-7}

\end{tabular}

%% Part 3 of 3: the tablenotes environment
\smallskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[] KP: Knotenpunkt, HS: Haltestelle
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Show us the code that makes the problem. Maybe you forgot to add the column to the parameter of the `tabular`.

Comment: could you perhaps add a hand sketch of the desired output

Comment: Sorry if i didnt explain my proplem well enough. I edited the picture to hopefully make things clearer. So i basically want the text (Fahrt Nr:,Linie:,Datum:) at the position of the box below, next to the diagonal text. I think where im stuck is that the height of the cells is defined by the diagonal text. I know my approach in the code is wrong, since im just adding a table on top of a table, but its the closest i could make it work to the result i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @jsbibra led me in the right direction and I got it working with \makecell .

Here is my solution in case anyone runs into a similar problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%% Rotation
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \rot } { m }
  { 
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1 em }
      { 
        \hbox_overlap_right:n 
          { 
            \skip_horizontal:n { \fp_to_dim:n { 7 * cosd (\Angle) } } 
            \rotatebox{\Angle}{#1}
          } 
      } 
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\Angle{45}

\begin{threeparttable}

%% Part 1 of 3: the caption
\caption*{Fahrtenprotokoll:}
\label{tab:protokoll}

%% Part 2 of 3: the table
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{2.25cm}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[bl]{Fahrt Nr:\\Linie:\\Datum:\\ \\ \\ \\ \makecell[bc]{KP}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{Bezeichnung}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen KP [s]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{\rot{Haltezeit LSA [s]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{\rot{Haltezeit HS [s]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{\rot{Fahrgastwechselzeit [s]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen HS [s]}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell[b]{Sonstiges}} \\ \hline
HS 1       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 1.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 1.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 2       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 2.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 2.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 3       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 3.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 3.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
HS 4       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 4.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
LSA 4.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
\multicolumn{3}{r|}{Gesamt:}  &  &  &  &     \\ \cline{4-7}
\end{tabular}

%% Part 3 of 3: the tablenotes environment
\smallskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item[] KP: Knotenpunkt, HS: Haltestelle
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Question was not quite clear so....

**Option1**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%% Rotation
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \rot } { m }
{ 
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1 em }
    { 
        \hbox_overlap_right:n 
        { 
            \skip_horizontal:n { \fp_to_dim:n { 7 * cosd (\Angle) } } 
            \rotatebox{\Angle}{#1}
        } 
    } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \def\Angle{45}
    
    \begin{threeparttable}
        
        %% Part 1 of 3: the caption
        
        \caption*{Fahrtenprotokoll:}
        \label{tab:protokoll}
        
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{2.25cm}|}
%           \cline{1-1}
%           \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Fahrt Nr:}\\ 
%           \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Linie: }\\
%           \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Datum: } \\ 
%           \cline{1-1}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Fahrt Nr:\\Linie:\\Datum:\\KP}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bezeichnung} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen KP [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit LSA [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit HS [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrgastwechselzeit [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen HS [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sonstiges} \\ \hline
            HS 1       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 1.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 1.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 2       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 2.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 2.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 3       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 3.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 3.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 4       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 4.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 4.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Gesamt:}  &  &  &  &     \\ \cline{4-7}
            
        \end{tabular}
        
        %% Part 3 of 3: the tablenotes environment
        \smallskip
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
            \item[] KP: Knotenpunkt, HS: Haltestelle
        \end{tablenotes}
        
    \end{threeparttable}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,threeparttable,caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

%% Rotation
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \rot } { m }
{ 
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1 em }
    { 
        \hbox_overlap_right:n 
        { 
            \skip_horizontal:n { \fp_to_dim:n { 7 * cosd (\Angle) } } 
            \rotatebox{\Angle}{#1}
        } 
    } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \def\Angle{45}
    
    \begin{threeparttable}
        
        %% Part 1 of 3: the caption
        
        \caption*{Fahrtenprotokoll:}
        \label{tab:protokoll}
        
        \begin{tabular}{|c|p{5cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{0.75cm}|p{2.25cm}|}
            \cline{1-1}
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Fahrt Nr:}\\ 
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Linie: }\\
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Datum: } \\ 
            \cline{1-1}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{KP} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bezeichnung} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen KP [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit LSA [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Haltezeit HS [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrgastwechselzeit [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\rot{Fahrzeit zwischen HS [s]}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sonstiges} \\ \hline
            HS 1       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 1.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 1.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 2       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 2.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 2.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 3       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 3.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 3.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            HS 4       &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 4.1    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \cline{1-4}
            LSA 4.2    &  &  &  &  &  &  &      \\ \Xhline{1.5pt}
            \multicolumn{3}{r|}{Gesamt:}  &  &  &  &     \\ \cline{4-7}
            
        \end{tabular}
        
        %% Part 3 of 3: the tablenotes environment
        \smallskip
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
            \item[] KP: Knotenpunkt, HS: Haltestelle
        \end{tablenotes}
        
    \end{threeparttable}
    
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]